# PHP APC and Pecl upload progress returning false/null

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is a long shot. I believe this might be suhosin patch issue.

Here is my php from codeigniter:

```
public function uploadprogress($id) {
    if ($id) {
        header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
        header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");

        echo json_encode(apc_fetch('upload_'.$id));
        exit();


    }
}
public function uploader() {

    $this->load->view('myid/' . $this->router->class . '_uploader');
    //phpinfo();
}
```

script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var progress_key = $('#progress_key').val();

            // this sets up the progress bar
            $('#uploadform').submit(function() {
                setTimeout(beginUpload,1500);

                return;
            });
            function beginUpload() {
                $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value:0}).fadeIn();
                var i = setInterval(function() {
                    $.getJSON("/myid/videos/uploadprogress/" + progress_key, function(data) {
                        alert('data');
                        if (data == null) {
                            clearInterval(i);
                            location.reload(true);
                            return;
                        }
                        var response;
                        eval ("response = " + data);

                        if (!response)
                            return;

                        var percentage = Math.floor(100 * parseInt(response['bytes_uploaded']) / parseInt(response['bytes_total']));
                        $("#progressbar").progressbar({value:percentage});
                    }, 1500);
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Has anyone had strange troubles with this before? The upload key is the same on the view and the uploadprogress method. I've Tried apc and pecl upload-progress both return false or null.
I wondering if it's just suhosin patch messing up everything?

Answer (score 1):

```
apc.rfc1867 = 1
```

Do you have this in you php.ini ? It is necessary to use APC upload progress feature